# Why am I not able to import a class into java file in Eclipse Maven Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, import, package

I need to use AuthenticationRequest in my Maven Java Project. I did a search on the internet and found AuthenticationRequest on this page ([OpenID Connect authentication](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-oauth-openid-connect-sdk/examples/openid-connect/oidc-auth)), indicating this library contains AuthenticationRequest. I follow the links on that website to this page ([com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk-6.13 API Doc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.nimbusds/oauth2-oidc-sdk/6.13)) and find a list of packages. I found this library at [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nimbusds/oauth2-oidc-sdk/6.13).

I added the information in my pom.xml in my Maven Project in Eclipse. Updated Project. Yet I am not able to import any packages starting with "com.nimbusds.oauth2".

Here is the dependency info for that library that I put in my pom.xml file:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nimbusds/oauth2-oidc-sdk -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>6.13</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am following an example code that uses the AuthenticationRequest class. I am having trouble finding the Maven info to put in my pom.xml file that allows me to use that class in my project. How do I find the right info for it?

Comment: Yes, it is. runtime means: I don't need it to compile my code (and don't want my code to be using the classes in this jar), but it's needed at runtime for my code to work. You typically use this for a database driver for example: the code needs the driver at runtime to connect to the database, but your code only uses standard JDBC types.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm getting an error when I try to use the class AuthenticationRequest. How do I use that class if I can't import it? That tag was included in the info Maven Repository gave me. Can I just leave that tag out?

Comment: set scope to compile and rerun your maven goal with -u (for update), you should pick up that dependency if your pom indeed specifies a repository that contains it (or if maven central contains it)

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Answer (score 0):

Since you are developing a class that depends on that AuthenticationRequest class to compile, your maven goal is going to be before runtime. Maven scope of runtime is not appropriate.

You need to modify your pom.xml to specify compile scope:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>6.13</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Since Maven's default scope is compile, you could also just omit the scope tag.

Maven will import dependencies from the Maven Central repository by default. If Maven Central doesn't contain your dependency (I haven't checked) you must specify a repository that does contain it with something of this form in your pom.xml (note the repo is just an example - substitute a real one that contains your dependency)

```
 <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>some-example-repo</id>
            <url>http://some.example.repo/some_example_path/</url>
        </repository>
  </repositories>
```